# Comparing timespan object if it's between hours in C#

Tags: c#, timespan

I want to filter an array of objects. The goal is to filter the objects between two timespan objects:

```
  TimeSpan tsFrom = TimeSpan.Parse("16:00");
  TimeSpan tsTo = TimeSpan.Parse("00:59");
```

For example I have this object:

```
TimeSpan dateObject = TimeSpan.Parse("22:05:22");
```

The problem comes when I try to compare if the dateObject is between tsFrom and tsTo:

```
if (dateObject > tsFrom && dateObject < tsTo)
{
// do something ....
}
```

This won't work for cases like that. Do you have any ideas how I can make this work ?

Comment: I don't follow the premise of the question. 22:05 does come after 00:59 -- why do you think that it should come before?

Comment: I would use DateTime object instead of TimeSpan.  Timespan only works when the times are in the same day.  Datetime works the same a TimeSpan but will compare properly with times that are not in the same Day.  You can always take a DateTime object and convert to TimeSpan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're wanting to works with times of day. The `TimeSpan` data type works with time spans (somewhat obvious to say). These are *distinct* concepts.

Times of day are precisely what motivated the creation of the new [`TimeOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timeonly?view=net-6.0) type in .NET 6. It has an [`IsBetween`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timeonly.isbetween?view=net-6.0#system-timeonly-isbetween(system-timeonly-system-timeonly)) method:

> Determines if a time falls within the range provided. Supports both "normal" ranges such as 10:00-12:00, and ranges that span midnight such as 23:00-01:00.

Note that `IsBetween` use the more sensible convention of inclusive start, exclusive end which means that you'd use `01:00` as the to moment and not accidentally exclude e.g. `00:59:17` from your period

---

For older versions, I'd suggest you realise that if `To` is less than `From` (e.g. it's representing a period that crosses midnight) you should check:

```
if ((tsTo > tsFrom && dateObject >= tsFrom && dateObject < tsTo) ||
    (tsFrom > tsTo && (dateObject < tsTo || dateObject >= tsFrom)))
{

}
```

Note, again, that this logic is assuming inclusive `From` and exclusive `To` (Your original logic treated both ends as exclusive which is rarely correct)

Comment: [FWIW, the `TimeOnly.IsBetween` implementation](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/TimeOnly.cs,05cb6ac4da259f44)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this one is that you're trying to use the timeSpan method in the wrong way, if I got it right you are trying to check if the dateObject time comes between tsFrom and tsTo, the problem is that you are trying to refer to a different day with the tsTo, something that timespan can not handle.
I fixed it using dateTime to specify at least the day the time is taken from, i suggest changing the code to this

```
        string datevalue = @"15/03/2021 16:00:00";
        DateTime start = DateTime.Parse(datevalue);

        datevalue = @"16/03/2021 00:59:00";
        DateTime end = DateTime.Parse(datevalue);

        datevalue = @"15/03/2021 22:05:22";
        DateTime obj = DateTime.Parse(datevalue);

        if (obj > start && obj < end)
        {
            //Do something
        }
```